# What will be output if I print local time return values?

Tags: perl, function

I printed the localtime return values without storing that into one variable, it is display some digits I don't know what is that, but if we use that return value in localtime and store that into scalar variable it is displaying some date format.

for example

```
print localtime,"\n";
```

its print output

```
713156411531250
```

then I give that output to arguments of localtime like

```
$time=localtime(713156411531250);
print "$time\n";
```

Output:

```
Sat Jan 14 16:37:30 22600997
```

Comment: Perhaps you could try reading [the documentation for the localtime function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl in general, and `localtime` specifically is magic - it knows in what context it's being used.

So you can use things like `wantarray()` within a sub to detect whether the caller is expecting multiple results.

[`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) is much the same.

If you 'use' it in a LIST context, it returns a list of values:

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
                                            localtime(time);
```

You are effectively doing this by 'just' printing it.

E.g.

```
print scalar localtime,"\n";
print join ( " ", localtime );
```

Gives:

```
Fri May  8 11:20:15 2015
15 20 11 8 4 115 5 127 1
```

Comment: if we give only `print localtime` what time it is return?

Comment: @Rajalakshmi it doesn't return a time; because you are calling it where a list is expected, it returns a list of sec, min, hour, and so on and you print them all joined together.  don't do that.

Comment: It returns list of date parts => `print join " ", localtime;`

Comment: @Сухой27 I know that if we give only local time its give current date and time but in print its not do like this

Comment: `print` is doing things in a list context. You are basically doing: `my @stuff = localtime(); print @stuff`. E.g. printing the resultant array. That's so you can `print function(),$variable,"\n";` - you're passing it a list when you do that.